# Javascript define getElementById() from php variable?

Tags: php, javascript, variables, loops

I have a shipping module I'm trying to update. I'd like to be able to add rows for each line item in my php form/table. What ends up happening is the add/delete row buttons show up for each line item as desired but only affect the first line item. If I add a row to line item 1 it adds a row properly. But if I go to add a row for line item 2 it actually adds a row for line item 1 as well. If I try to add a row for line item 3 it again adds a line for item 1. I want to be able to add rows for each item.

I have a while loop in php that calls a javascript function.  Problem is that one of the variables in the javascript requires an ID.  Despite going through my loop the ID never changes and therefore my javascript only applies to a single loop which is not my desired output.  I'm thinking if I can have the javascript receive a variable from PHP that contains my ID I can get the javascript to run for each pass through my loop.

Here is my javascript:

```
    <SCRIPT language="javascript">
      // Last updated 2006-02-21
function addRowToTable()
{
  var tbl = document.getElementById('tblSample');
  var lastRow = tbl.rows.length;
  // if there's no header row in the table, then iteration = lastRow + 1
  var iteration = lastRow + 1;
  var row = tbl.insertRow(lastRow);

  // Item cell
  var cellLeft = row.insertCell(0);
  var textNode = document.createTextNode(iteration);
  cellLeft.appendChild(textNode);

  // Cust PN cell
  var cellBox_Num = row.insertCell(1);
  var el = document.createElement('input');
  el.type = 'text';
  el.name = 'Box_Num[]';
  el.id = 'Box_Num' + iteration;
  el.size = 18;

  el.onkeypress = keyPressTest;
  cellBox_Num.appendChild(el);
}
function keyPressTest(e, obj)
{
  var validateChkb = document.getElementById('chkValidateOnKeyPress');
  if (validateChkb.checked) {
    var displayObj = document.getElementById('spanOutput');
    var key;
    if(window.event) {
      key = window.event.keyCode; 
    }
    else if(e.which) {
      key = e.which;
    }
    var objId;
    if (obj != null) {
      objId = obj.id;
    } else {
      objId = this.id;
    }
    displayObj.innerHTML = objId + ' : ' + String.fromCharCode(key);
  }
}
function removeRowFromTable()
{
  var tbl = document.getElementById('tblSample');
  var lastRow = tbl.rows.length;
  if (lastRow > 1) tbl.deleteRow(lastRow - 1);
}

    </SCRIPT>
```

Here is my loop:

```
<?php

$i=0;
$n=1;

while($i < $num1) {

$SO_Line_Item=mysql_result($result1,$i,"SO_Line_Item");
$Cust_PN=mysql_result($result1,$i,"Cust_PN");
$Cust_PN_Rev=mysql_result($result1,$i,"Cust_PN_Rev");
$Description=mysql_result($result1,$i,"Description");
$SOItemQty=mysql_result($result1,$i,"Qty");
$UOM=mysql_result($result1,$i,"UOM");
$Program=mysql_result($result1,$i,"Program");
$Required_Date=mysql_result($result1,$i,"Required_Date");   
$SOItemShipQty=mysql_result($result2,$i,"count(E9_SN)"); 

?>
<tr>
<td width="3px" valign="top" align="center"><?php
echo "$SO_Line_Item";?>
</td>
<td nowrap="nowrap" valign="top" align="center"><?php
echo "$Cust_PN - $Cust_PN_Rev";?>
</td>
<td nowrap="nowrap" valign="top" align="center"><?php
echo "$Description";?>
</td>
<td nowrap="nowrap" valign="top" align="center">
<?php
echo "$SOItemQty";?>
</td>
<td nowrap="nowrap" valign="top" align="center">
<?php
echo "$UOM";?>
</td>
<td nowrap="nowrap" valign="top" align="center">
<?php
echo $SOItemQty - $SOItemShipQty;?>
</td>
<td nowrap="nowrap" valign="top" align="center">
<input size="2" align="right" type="text" name="Qty">
</td>
<td nowrap="nowrap" valign="top" align="center">
<?php
echo "$Required_Date";?>
</td>
<td nowrap="nowrap" valign="top" align="center">
<?php
echo "$Program";?>
</td>
</tr>

//HERE IS WHERE THINGS GO SOUTH.  I'd LIKE TO BE ABLE TO ADD A LINE FOR EACH PART 
//NUMBER... WHAT HAPPENS IS THIS IS ALWAYS RUN FOR THE SAME ID AND WHILE THE FORM 
//DISPLAYS PROPERLY THE ADD AND DELETE ALWAYS MODIFY THE FIRST PART

<tr>
<td colspan="10">
<p>
<input type="button" value="Add" onclick="addRowToTable();" />
<input type="button" value="Remove" onclick="removeRowFromTable();" />
<!-- 
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="validateRow(this.form);" />
<input type="checkbox" id="chkValidate" /> Validate Submit  
-->
<b><font color="RED">Add/Remove Box Number For This Line Item</font></b>
</p>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td></td>
<td>
<table id="tblSample">
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="Box_Num[]"
     id="Box_Num1" size="18" onkeypress="keyPressTest(event, this);" /></td>

  </tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
<?php



$i++;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am not following.  Your PHP does not 'call' a javascript function, nor would it be able to.  If you are asking if you can generate unique id in your HTML using PHP and then have those unique ID's actined upon in javascript, the answer is yes, this is very easy. Just increment a counter or whatever in your PHP loop and add the increment value to the ID like id="id_X" where X is your counter output.

Comment: You are correct, this is what I'm trying to do. To be a bit more specific, In my php I set table id="tblSample". In the Javascript function addrow() for example looks for id="tblSample" via "var tbl=document.getElementById('tblSample');" I'm thinking if I can as you said change "tblSample" to say a php variable of $tblSample that increments with each pass through the loop and then change the javascript to "var tbl = document.getElementById('$tblSample');" or something similar. Since the "var tbl" piece is within function addRowToTable() I wasn't sure how this works. Thanks for taking the time!

Comment: OK.  It is still unclear what you are actually trying to do.  Are you trying add/delete rows on tblSample, or the larger table in which these are nested?

Comment: I have a shipping module I'm trying to update. I'd like to be able to add rows for each line item in my php form/table. What ends up happening is the add/delete row buttons show up for each line item as desired but only affect the first line item. If I add a row to line item 1 it adds a row properly. But if I go to add a row for line item 2 it actually adds a row for line item 1 as well. If I try to add a row for line item 3 it again adds a line for item 1. I want to be able to add rows for each item. Hope this helps and Thank you.

Comment: That is because you have multiple items with the same id.  Id's should be unique.  When you are selecting by tblSample id, it will only select the first element with that id that is encountered in the DOM. So you just need to number your ids and reference the ID's in when calling the javascript function (like pass the id in the function onclick function parameter.

Comment: Got it... that's what I was thinking. My challenge is I am unsure what passing the id in the function would look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply pass a table id into your row addition and deleletion javascript functions.  You could change the first couple line of both function to be like this:

```
function addRowToTable(tableID)
{
    var tbl = document.getElementById('tblSample_' + tableID);
    ...
}
```

You would also use your PHP counter to pass the table counter value to the javascript functions like this

```
<input type="button" value="Add" onclick="addRowToTable('<?php echo $i; ?>');" />
<input type="button" value="Remove" onclick="removeRowFromTable('<?php echo $i; ?>');" />
```

and add the counter to the table id's like this.

```
<table id="tblSample_<?php echo $i; ?>">
```

Comment: Worked like a charm!  Thank you for your time and patience!